# How can I fix pymongo server selection timeout error

Tags: python, pymongo

I am totally newbie to mongodb and pymongo. Yesterday for a small project I started to test how nosql might feels. but, I can't do anything with it because of server selection time out error

This is the whole code

```py
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")

ContactsDB = client["ContactsDB"]

ContactsCollection = ContactsDB["ContactsCollection"]

to_insert = { "name": f"{name}", "phone": f"{phone}"}

ContactsCollection.insert_one(to_insert)
```

And this is the error

```
  File "main.py", line 20, in add_contact
    x = ContactsCollection.insert_one(mydict)
  File "/home/erfan2003/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 700, in insert_one
    session=session),
  File "/home/erfan2003/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 614, in _insert
    bypass_doc_val, session)
  File "/home/erfan2003/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 602, in _insert_one
    acknowledged, _insert_command, session)
  File "/home/erfan2003/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1279, in _retryable_write
    with self._tmp_session(session) as s:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/home/erfan2003/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1611, in _tmp_session
    s = self._ensure_session(session)
  File "/home/erfan2003/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1598, in _ensure_session
    return self.__start_session(True, causal_consistency=False)
  File "/home/erfan2003/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1551, in __start_session
    server_session = self._get_server_session()
  File "/home/erfan2003/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1584, in _get_server_session
    return self._topology.get_server_session()
  File "/home/erfan2003/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 429, in get_server_session
    None)
  File "/home/erfan2003/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 200, in _select_servers_loop
    self._error_message(selector))
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27027: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: check your mongod service. is it started ?